# Prevent Image Stacking in Mailchimp (html/css)

Tags: html, css, image, mailchimp

I'm currenly working on an email in Mailchimp. I wanted an email that looked like this on mobile. Mailchimp's default behaviour is to stack images on mobile, so I had to get a custom code snippet to make this work.

[image]

It works on most devices, but on some (like Iphone 6s) I get the following behaviour. 
[image]

Any ideas why this happens or how to fix it?

Here's the code that I used:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="0" position="center" style="width:100%; max-width: 100px;" width="100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="70%"><a href="https://testlink.com" border="0" src="testimage.png"/></a></td>
            <td width="0%"><a href="https://testlink.com" border="0" src="testimage.png"/></a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```